# Filtro com dois DropDowList ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

Gostaria de fazer um filtro com dois `DropDownList`. No primeiro filtro são filtradas as Unidades cadastradas e no segundo as Funções cadastradas naquela unidade, com seus respectivos Funcionários. O resultado final seria a lista dos Funcionários referente àquela função no `Grid`.

O Filtro funciona no `GridView`, mas não filtrado a função de acordo com a unidade escolhida.

**Model CNES**

```
public int CNESID { get; set; }
public string UnidadeID { get; set; }
public string Funcao { get; set; }
public string NomeProfissional { get; set; }
public string CPF { get; set; }
```

**Controller**

```
 public class CNESController : Controller
 {
        private PortalPainelEntities db = new PortalPainelEntities();

        // GET: /CNES/
        public ActionResult Index(int? pagina, string currentFilter, string Pesquisa)
        {
            int tamanhopagina = 15;
            int numeropagina = pagina ?? 1;

            if (Pesquisa != null)
            {
                pagina = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                Pesquisa = currentFilter;
            }

            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = Pesquisa;

            var cnes = from s in db.CNES select s;


            //Metodo do Filtro para o Grid View

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Pesquisa))
            {
                cnes = cnes.Where(p =>   p.NomeUnidade.ToUpper().Contains(Pesquisa.ToUpper())
                                         || p.Funcao.ToUpper().Contains(Pesquisa.ToUpper()));
            }

            return View(cnes.OrderBy(p => p.Nr_Cnes).ToPagedList(numeropagina, tamanhopagina));
        }

        //Lista de Unidades via JSon

        public JsonResult ObterUnidade()
        {
            var unidadeLista = (from u in db.CNES
                                select new
                                {
                                    u.NomeUnidade
                                }).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.NomeUnidade);

            return Json(unidadeLista, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        //Lista de Funções via Json, filtrando por Unidade.

        public JsonResult ObterFuncao(string unidade)
        {
            var funcao = db.CNES
                .Where(a => a.NomeUnidade == unidade)
                .Select(a => new { a.Funcao }).Distinct()
                .OrderBy(a => a.Funcao);

            return Json(funcao, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

**View**

`DropDownlist`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

                <div class="col-md-4">
                        @Html.DropDownList("NomeUnidade",
                        new SelectList(string.Empty, "NomeUnidade", "NomeUnidade"), "Selecione a Unidade",
                        new { @class = "form-control", @id = "unidade" })



                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        @Html.DropDownList("Pesquisa",
                        new SelectList(string.Empty, "Funcao", "Funcao"), "Selecione a Função",
                        new  {@class = "form-control", @id = "funcao" })
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Buscar" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
}
```

Script para popular os `DropDownList`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $.getJSON('/CNES/ObterUnidade', function (data) {
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $('#unidade').append('<option value="' +
                data[i].NomeUnidade + '">' + data[i].NomeUnidade + '</option');
            }

        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Erro ao obter a Unidade!');
        });
    });

    $('#unidade').change(function () {
        var unidade = $(this).find(":selected").val();


        $.getJSON('/CNES/ObterFuncao', { unidade: unidade }, function (data) {

            $('#funcao option').remove();

            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $('#funcao').append('<option value="' +
                data[i].Funcao + '">' + data[i].Funcao + '</option');
            }

        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // Ajax fail callback function.
            alert('Erro ao obter a Função.!');
        });
    });
```

Comment: Sua Action Post possui somente um parametro "Pesquisa". Onde esta o parametro para a Unidade?

Comment: `GridView`? Está usando Web Forms? O código parece certo.